# VBA Excel Charts: Enter Array as XValue on Date Axis

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to create/modify an Excel line chart with a Date x-axis using VBA and assigning the Series.Xvalues using an array rather than a range:

```
Sub test()
  Dim c As Chart: Set c = ActiveChart
  With c.SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = Array(42228, 42229, 42235, 42277, 42338, 42613)        
    .Values = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  
  End With
End Sub
```

The problem is when I run that the .resulting .XValues are of type Variant/String rather than Variant/Double, so the chart shows as if the x-axis were a Text axis rather than a Date axis (i.e. the points appear evenly spaced along the x-axis):

[image]

However if I save the file, close it and then reopen it magically appears as a Date axis, with the points spaced along the x-axis according to their true distance:

[image]

If I inspect the Series.XValues object after reopening, the array elements have been transformed into Variant/Double. I tried coercing them manually before reopening but it causes Excel to crash. Actually even if I just copy the chart it's enough to make it appear properly, so somehow Excel "knows" it's a date axis but is just not showing it as such. I'm going to have to use that as the solution (i.e. make a copy and delete the old one whenever I change the chart), however it's pretty clunky and I would love to figure out what's going on here. I found this http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66504 but he doesn't seem to have the same problem. I'm using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute this expression in the Immediate Window:

```
TypeName(Array(42228, 42229, 42235, 42277, 42338, 42613)(1))
```

VBA returns "Long". So I believe your input is already numeric.

I think Excel is "helping you" by changing the number format of your tick labels to a non-date format. You can change the format back to date with something like this:

```
ch.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks I tried that but the `TickLabels.NumberFormat` is already in a date format and playing around with it doesn't seem to help

Comment: That's curious --- it worked for me when I ran your code with the new line of code added. I'm using Excel 2010, what version are you using?

Comment: Excel 2010 v14 32-bit

Comment: Maybe this behavior is related to the chart type. The code example I gave works for scatter charts. When I tried it with line charts, it looked similar to your chart before close and re-open. Try experimenting with the scatter charts: c.ChartType=xlXYScatterLines

Comment: You're right, xlXYScatterLines works as it should. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When your X value array was passed in, they were not in a date format. Excel, being ever so helpful, decided the axis was no longer a date scale axis. But you can easily fix that:

```
Sub test()
  Dim c As Chart
  Set c = ActiveChart
  With c.SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = Array(42228, 42229, 42235, 42277, 42338, 42613)
    .Values = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  End With
  With c.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
    .CategoryType = xlTimeScale
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/dd/yy"
  End With
End Sub
```

My initial thought, which didn't work, was to enter the values as dates:

```
Array(#8/12/2015#, #8/13/2015#, #8/19/2015#, #9/30/2015#, #11/30/2015#, #8/31/2016#)
```

but this made the axis behave as a text axis, with the dates equally spaced. Although the Date Axis option was selected, the rest of the axis options was the same as a text axis, and didn't show the date scaling section of a date axis.

Comment: Thanks Jon, actually it wasn't changing the axis type. My solution is to use scatter line charts when I can and when it has to be a line chart then I wrote a macro to make a copy in the same position (and delete the old one) which forces it to appear the way it should

Comment: If you use my procedure, you don't need to recreate the chart (and hose any custom formatting you've applied). Resetting the category type and number format makes the chart look right.